# Installing sharepoint web service disabled when trying to install BizTalk adapter

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-services

I have a MOSS Box, with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 SP2 (Danish server), .net 3.5 SP1 on a Server 2008 64 bit (where IIS is running 64 bit too).

When I fire up the BizTalk installer and wants to select the SharePoint Web Service, this option is disabled/grayed out.

Any ideas as how I can enable the option again? (It states that there are one or more prerequisites missing but I can't figure out which).

I found some reference stating that I basically had to "toast" the MOSS box and install WSS 3, but that is NOT an option...

Any suggestions? :o)

Answer (score 1):

We succeeded in getting the web service running on MOSS by installing on a basic WSS 3 / Biztalk server and moving the web service to the MOSS server (copy application folder and add to central admin web application, copy and install required BizTalk dll's to target server GAC (4 in this case).

I have no clue as to why we could not install ot using the BizTalk installer, but it runs fine now none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following conditions from [Known Issues with the Windows Sharepoint Services Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727787(BTS.10,lightweight).aspx) apply:

- Windows SharePoint Services 2.0 SP2 and the Windows SharePoint Services 2.0 Language Template Pack are installed on the BizTalk Server computer.
- You have uninstalled Windows SharePoint Services 2.0 SP2 without uninstalling the Windows SharePoint Services 2.0 Language Template Pack.
- You have installed Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.

Although the above article suggest re-installing WSS, I think it is just excluding MOSS from the equation because it isn't required. It is supported though:

> The BizTalk Server Windows SharePoint
>   Services Adapter web service can be
>   installed and configured on a web site
>   that has been extended as a Microsoft
>   Office SharePoint Server 2007 (MOSS)
>   web application. The BizTalk Server
>   Windows SharePoint Services Adapter
>   can also connect to a web site that
>   has been extended as a MOSS web
>   application.

*From [Windows SharePoint Services Support in BizTalk Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb743377(BTS.10).aspx)*

You can follow the steps to [Reinstall MOSS during a Gradual Upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/ekraus/archive/2008/05/28/reinstall-moss-during-gradual-upgrade.aspx) to matain a basic level of service while you are reinstalling WSS/MOSS.

Comment: It's a seperate server install so it should not rely on any BizTalk server installation. The installation is created as MOSS 2007 out of the box. Tried both with SP 1 and SP 2 but none of those optoins enabled the web service installation